# How to stub a function inside ComponentDidMount and requires to render the component first?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs

I'm trying to unit test a react component as below:

Component.jsx:

```
return React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
                <div id='model' ref = 'model' >
                    <div className = 'container'>
                        {container}
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
    }

    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.props.model.getNext().then(doSth());

        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.model).addEventListener('focus', this.scroll);
    },

    scroll: function() {
        // do scrolling.
    }
});
```

So I wanted to test the logic inside componentDidMount, which requires to stub the addEventListener().
The problem is:
to stub it I need to render to get find the domnode by the refs property, but the componentDidMount will be called right after the render, so the stub doesn't work on that case.

Eg: in the unit test:

```
var eventFunction = {};
mockEventListener: function(event, callback){
    eventFunction[event] = callback;
}

var renderer = React.addons.TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(component, props);
sinon.sandbox.create().stub(React.findDOMNode(renderer.refs.model), 'addEventListener', mockEventListener);
eventFunction.focus();
```

This will complain that the eventFunction doesn't have any property as the stub is called after componentDidMount being executed so it's nevered get stubed.
Is there any way to stub the function before the render or any other approach to test this unit properly?